# How to test P&T's field pack checkbox, unchecked

Tags: pixelandtonic, conditionals, field-pack

I want to test for a single unchecked checkbox using P&T's field pack checkbox. Anyone know the syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need **[:selected](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/fieldtypes/checkboxes/tags.html#selected-tag)** tag

> For use in conditionals; returns whether or not a particular option is selected.

```
{if '{my_checkboxes_field:selected option="kittens"}' == '0'}
  <p>No Kittens :'(</p>
{/if}
```